# Revolut and Taiwan dollar payment

Tags: foreign-exchange

Urgent question. Revolut does not support Taiwan dollar but I am not sure whether we can reserve hotel for example online payment in Taiwan dollar and what is the exchange rate in case I want to be deducted from PLN (Polish zloty) account?

Answer (score -4):

1 PLN = 6.50927 TWD (1 TWD = .15363 PLN)

Comment: Thanksm my question is not that. Specifically revolut